# How to just make a specific link colorful?

Tags: php, css

I did not want to make all links on my custom blog red. Just specific ones. Only the "Destiny" text and "Read more" should be red color. As you can see the titles is also red and that's what I don't want. All links should be red but not the titles!

Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/daaa771613ffd444b65e38119c45c2dd

How can I fix this, what needs to be done?

Thank you

Comment: Add another class/style to title?

Comment: Can you post the code of the blog page with title? @u_mulder is right, you have to find a way to add a new class specific for title

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please follow the instruction for asking a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

You can add a specific rule for links inside your titles

```
h1 a { color: red}

a { color: blue}
```

or create some extra class and add them in your markup:

```
//html
<h1 class="title-link">My title</h1>

//css
.title-link {
  color: red;
}

a {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it is by adding a class attribute to each element you want to be red:

```
<a class="red-text">Read more</a>
<a class="red-text">another red text</a>
```

and then in the stylesheet you can select them:

```
.red-text {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hello thank, look at my reply. I added the code so you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<h1 class="title">This Title should be black</h1>
```

css

```
.title{
color:black;
}
```

Sample

```
<?php
            try {

                $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC');
                while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

                    echo '<div>';
                        echo '<h1 class="title"><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
                        echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
                        echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';             
                        echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';               
                    echo '</div>';

                }

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
<?php
try {
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC');
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
        echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
        echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';             
        echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';               
        echo '</div>';
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this . I hop This code helpfully

```
    // Html Code
    <label class="Red-color"> Title Name </label>

    // Css 
    .Red-color
    {
    color: red;
    /* if you want underline */
     text-decoration: underline;
    }
```